# WP Elementor: Filter archive posts by date (f.e. via custom query)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I do know that you can set custom queries with the Elementor plugin but only a few widget support this f.e. the Post-Widget. But I want to set a custom query with the "Archive Post"-Widget of Elementor.

**I want to group all my posts by year.** (On top of each row there should also be the title of the year)

Do you know how to do that? Maybe via changing the php code itself? 
Where does Elementor has his php code for the page?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this with an additional plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-yearly-archive/. I still had to tweak it a bit to display in columns and use actual heading tags for the years but it was the best option I could find since Elementor didn't have an answer for this.